# How to add a QStackLayout to only part of an application?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside

I need a method to have several pages on one application like QStackLayout does but I need to to only cover part of my window such as the example below:

[image: 1]

The current method I can think of is have several frames and then just disabling and setting then to not be visible, however I need this app to be memory efficient and I don't believe that this solution will lead to that.

And just to make sure, will QStackedLayout be memory efficient so I can have quite a lot of pages in it, e.g. 30+ with each qwidget having 30-40 gui components/widgets, or will it be more efficient to have the several Qframe and then disabling and making them invisible and setting another one to be enabled and visible.

Do the widgets become disabled when they are not visible because I do not want a user to miss click a visible button and they somehow click a button they cant see which is in another qwidget?

Comment: Just use a top level layout (in this case, probably a QHBoxLayout), then add nested layouts or widgets, with the buttons on the left and the stack on the right. Note that: 1. generally speaking, you should normally prefer QStackedWidget; 2. widgets normally have a quite small memory footprint (~10-15kB, even less for simpler widgets), with nowadays computers, you can have *thousands* of widgets without affecting OS memory (I made a test with 10k buttons, and the difference in usage from startup was about 45mB, about 4kb each); 3. disabled or invisible widgets cannot receive input events.

Comment: For the QStackLayout, can it only hold a qwidget or can I use a qframe or does it even matter? I am treating the qwidgets individually, so I make the the qwidget and then add the widgets/components  and then add it to the stack and do this for all other widgets, is this the correct procedure.

Comment: QFrame *is* a QWidget: all Qt widgets inherit from QWidget at some level (see the "Inherits" section in the header of each class documentation, such as that of [QFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html)). So, yes, if you have a container that has child widgets, you add those widgets to the layout of that container, and then you add the container to the stack. Note that while there's nothing wrong in using QStackedLayout, it's normally better and simpler to use the convenience class QStackedWidget.

Comment: but what is the difference between QStackedWidget and QStackedLayout, are they the same bit thQStacked widegt cover the entire page and only QWidgets can be added?

Comment: They are fundamentally the same, but since QStackedWidget *is* a widget, it's easier to use it in other containers or situation that would require a widget anyway (such as QSplitter or QMainWindow).

Comment: So QStackwidget is visually like a frame, it hold things just like a frame would in QT Designer, QStackWidget is the area where the StackLayout will be added

Comment: More or less (where "frame" is in the generic sense of the term, not as in Qt frame, QFrame, which is a *styled* widget). Fundamentally it's exactly like tab widget, but without the tab bar: in fact, QTabWidget is actually a composed widget, made of a QTabBar and a QStackedWidget.

Comment: Perfect, so to add my StackLayout to just the left hand side, i can place a QStackWidget there and then add QWidgets to that QStackWidget and the stack layout will only apply there. Would the syntax for adding QWidgets to a QStackWidget be the same as adding them to a QStackLayout?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're asking, especially considering that what you want to change is on the **right** side. The contents of the stack are what is going to change and being shown, not the "controller" part that allows the user to select what to display. I suggest you to take your time carefully study the documentation and do some experimenting using Qt Designer in order to understand how these widgets work.

Comment: sorry, I meant on the right hand side not left hand side, if I put the widget there will it act just like the QTabWidget